# CSS - Paragraph styling with a DIV class

Tags: css

Simple CSS but I can not seem to control the styling of my paragraph tags within a div that has a class supplied.

Here is the example:

```
.body-content-white, div.body-content-white p  {
color:#FFFFFF;
font-family:Helvetica, Gotham, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
bgcolor="#52c2e9"
}


<div class="body-content-white"> 
<p> Welcome to the first Newsletter
</p> 
</div>
```

This is what I have tried:

```
div.body-content-white p, p .body-content-white, .body-content-white p
```

The solution was to add an !important; tag to the CSS Colour as follows:

```
.body-content-white, div.body-content-white > p  {
color:#FFFFFF; !important;
font-family:Helvetica, Gotham, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
bgcolor="#52c2e9"
}
```

I could also fix the issue by removing the `<div></div>` and adding the class to the `<td></td>` of my content.

Comment: edit you post please, and post your css cleanly.

Comment: Please post the html too.

Comment: Your `div` isn't closed, you have another opening `div`, did you intend that? It's invalid HTML as it stands.

Comment: No - it's not like that in my code - just poor copy paste

Comment: You have three errors in your declaration for the background colour. Also the `!important` in our last code block doesn't do anything, since it's in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have

```
<div class="body-content-white"> 
<p> Welcome to the first Newsletter</p> 
</div>
```

Then

```
.body-content-white p{
//your style
}
```

or

```
div.body-content-white p{
//your style
}
```

Should be working. If the css is not working then check if your stylesheet file is linked correctly inside your `<head>` tag (in other words check if the source path is correct).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.body-content-white > p
```

Or if not, something else in your css could be overriding it. Try adding

```
!important
```

with a space inbetween that and the value, such as at http://jsfiddle.net/ShJt6/

Comment: Why would that work if `div.body-content-white p` isn't? We need to see a reproducible example.

Comment: .body-content-white, div.body-content-white p  {
     color:#FFFFFF;
            font-family:Helvetica, Gotham, Arial, sans-serif;
     font-size:14px;
 }

Comment: @WLF14 - Please update the question with your details and code revisions.

Comment: Yes - That works! Thanks. Just thought it was best practice not to use the !important as I am designing for HTML email.

Comment: Also works if I apply the class to the TD rather than the DIV and remove the DIV altogether